# Cannot display a List of string inside an Object List in XAML, Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

My Model is

```
class MainPageList
    {   
        public string item { get; set; }
        public List<string> sitem { get; set; }
        public List<string> ssitem { get; set; }
    }
```

and My View Model is

```
 class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public List<MainPageList> MList { 
         get{
             return new List<MainPageList>
                {
                    new MainPageList(){item="Item1",sitem= new List<string>{"sub item1","sub item2","sub item3"}, ssitem= new List<string>{"sub sub item1","sub sub item2","sub sub item3"}}
                };
            }        
        }
        public string item { get; set; }
        public List<string> sitem { get; set; }
        public List<string> ssitem { get; set; } 
    }
```

and XAML is

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="Introcduction Page" Font="18" />
    <ListView x:Name="MainPageList" ItemsSource="{Binding MList} " >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <StackLayout>
              <Label Text="{Binding item} "></Label>
                 <StackLayout Padding="10,10,0,0">
                    <Label  Text="{Binding sitem} "></Label>
                       <StackLayout Padding="10,10,0,0">
                         <Label  Text="{Binding ssitem} "></Label>
                       </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>    
  </StackLayout>
```

I can get the text for *sitem* but *sitem* and *ssitem* are not being displayed in **Emulator** or **Device**.
Any help appreciated in advance, please.

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a List to a StackLayout and have it automatically "inflate" the data.  You can either use a ListView (which will apply a template to each item in the List) or manually build the collection of child objects that you want to display in your StackLayout.

Comment: I would suggest going for a generic ItemsControl rather than ListView unless you need all the extra functionality

Comment: @MikeT - this is Xamarin.Forms, not WPF.

Comment: @Jason..Thanks....I would prefer to use ListView...Could you please guide me...shd I use List view insider the List View???

Comment: just replicate the setup of your existing ListView, nested inside of the original one.  This should work, but it may not be very performant

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind a list into a `Label`. It should be a primitive type or a `Class` which implements `ToString()` method. If you want to show all items into a `Label` you can write a `Converter` like:

```
public class ListToString : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is IEnumerable)
        {
            string retval ="";
            for(string item in (IEnumerable)value) //use your string format here
                retval+= item+",";
            return retval;
        }

        else 
            return "";

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and use it on WPF side:

```
<!--define static resource -->
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <Converters:ListToString x:Key="ListToString"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

<!--use it -->
<Label  Text="{Binding sitem,Converter={StaticResource ListToString}} "></Label>
```